# Execute tasks related to process startup

Tags: android, android-activity, process, android-service, startup

Suppose that an Android app has multiple entry points: activities, services started by the system, etc.

And suppose we need to perform some tasks when the app (meaning any component of it) is starting with any of the above options. To put it in some context, suppose we need to initialize crash reporting system.

Putting code at every antry point (`Activity.onCreate()`, `Service..onCreate()`) is the first thing that comes into mind, but it looks like there should be a better approach.

What is the practice to implement it?

Comment: please explain in detail. 
if you call Activity.onCreate(), it is very bad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The usual approach is to place that code in [Application.onCreate()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html#onCreate()) which is
*called when the application is starting, before any activity, service, or receiver objects (excluding content providers) have been created*. This is how many libraries like Fabric/Crashlytics are initialized.

Comment: Thank you. This question arose when I enabled Fabric Crashlytics. That's a shame that their code sample in their Android Studio plugin actually contains code for initialization in `Activity.onCreate()` rather than more correct in `Application.onCreate()`.

Comment: The likely cause for that is there was no Application class so it chose to add it to the launch Activity. If you already have an Application class I think it will add the initializing code there.

Comment: I didn't use auto install. I mean their guides don't mention setup in an Application class at all. See [here](https://fabric.io/kits/android/crashlytics/install) for instance.